# "IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized" error

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get a marker with an custom icon in Google Maps Android API v2. I just changed one of the examples Google provides. I added `.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow))` to RawMapViewDemoActivity in method `setUpMap().`

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((MapView) findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Marker")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
}
```

But I'm always getting an "IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized".

```
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapdemo/com.example.mapdemo.RawMapViewDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.at.a(Unknown Source)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.d(Unknown Source)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Unknown Source)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at com.example.mapdemo.RawMapViewDemoActivity.setUpMap(RawMapViewDemoActivity.java:67)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at com.example.mapdemo.RawMapViewDemoActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(RawMapViewDemoActivity.java:58)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at com.example.mapdemo.RawMapViewDemoActivity.onCreate(RawMapViewDemoActivity.java:43)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-18 15:40:54.356: E/AndroidRuntime(12591):    ... 11 more
```

In [BitmapDescriptorFactory](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory) it says:

> Prior to using any methods from this class, you must do one of the following to ensure that this class is initialized:
>
> - Wait for a GoogleMap to become available from a MapFragment or MapView that you have added to your application. You can verify that the GoogleMap is available by calling the getMap() method and checking that the returned object is not null.
> - Call MapsInitializer.initialize(Context). As long as a com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException isn't thrown, this class will be correctly initialized.

I did the first one, but still getting this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest creating a sample project that can reproduce the error and posting its source code somewhere. This feels like a bug in `fromResource()`, but we'd need a reproducible test case.

Comment: Calling `MapInitializer.initialize()` does the trick for me.

Comment: i am facing the same problem..java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized

Comment: my sample java class:-http://pastebin.com/Mh7R0WQV

Comment: The same error "IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized" happens if I use the defaultMarker() method instead of the fromResource(). `.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)`

Comment: I've got same message when no Google account was on phone. So, you can try to check registered account on device.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Call `MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext())` in the `onCreate()`

Comment: @Greeny It throws an Exception

Comment: This is a good answer, however it would be great to find out why that really happens in the first place, it's not documented in the maps tutorial AFAIK

Comment: My application still crashes on some phones with this exception even though I have added this line of code. I found it may have something todo with GooglePlay store not installed or up to date. Any way to find out if Maps is available?

Comment: I am try this but same error nothing change in error

Comment: If you have the map inside a fragment please move that line to the fragment activity onCreate()

Comment: The right answer is from @Charlie, you should move your code to be called at 'onMapReady()'.

Comment: Even though this is a solution, it's not a good one since it doesn't work on all android devices.

The best solution is to call/use this class after your Map is loaded and ready. Once the map is loaded and ready, a callback is received via the `onMapReady()` method, as mentioned by @Charlie in an answer below.

Answer (score 24):

Move your code to be called `onMapReady()`, a callback provided by the GoogleMaps API.

Comment: It worked (when I triggere MapsInitializer in onCreate) on Galaxy s3 when I placed in onCreate and failed in s5 (and emulator). Moved to onMapReady helped, cheers!

Comment: This is actually the right answer. Other solutions don't work on all mobiles.

Answer (score 23):

Call following in `onCreate()`

```
try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I get a message, the exception is never thrown in this try catch block?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and finally In my case what I could find was the google play services were not installed. So installed them and app did not crash. So may be one can put try and a dialog saying so in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

See [Custom marker in google maps in android with vector asset icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365658/custom-marker-in-google-maps-in-android-with-vector-asset-icon).

In my case I had markers over Google Maps. But on API 19 emulator there is a problem with `Google Play Services`. So this error is misleading, `Google Play Services` tried to create `BitmapDescriptor`, but could not.

You should create markers in `onMapReady()`, also move there any other code, working with `Google Maps`.

If you have problems with showing Google Maps on Android 4, maybe you should downgrade a library from 16.1.0 to 16.0.0, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54772374/2914140. But if you do so, you will get a crash on Androif 9, see [Google Maps crashing on Android Pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139199/google-maps-crashing-on-android-pie/52139307).

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a solution that's work for me, i found it accidentally !
just upgrade your Gradle to
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability=GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

  int status=googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());



  if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(getActivity(),status,requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    }else {}
```