# Google Maps crashing on Android Pie

Tags: android, google-maps

I am testing Google Map on Google Pixel running the latest version of Android Pie.

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This error occurs on Android 9.0. 
Add the below code in the `<application>` element of manifest

```
<uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

Refer to [Specify requirement for Apache HTTP Legacy library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library) docs.

Answer (score 4):

Google map is not property supported android 9+. Use the following code in your manifest file. it will work.

```
 <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Anubhav Gupta, you can also update in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
```

But this can brake a compatibility with Android 4, see [App is having trouble with Google Play Services. Please try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771375/app-is-having-trouble-with-google-play-services-please-try-again/).